# What is placed at the end of hex file generated by Keil

Tags: arm, stm32, keil

I've found a problem I cannot answer. I've been placing a table of 3 bytes after the section where my program lies:

```
const uint8 AppVersion[] __attribute__((at(0x08006E00))) = {1,1,3);
```

What I've get in hex generated by Keil was the table plus extra data:
[End of hex file after data added at arbitrary address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bC13.png).

Whereas while not using aforementioned table I've get the same "extra" data (364 bytes) at the end of the hex:
[End of hex file normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV4EJ.png).

Could you tell me what is placed at the end of the application? I haven't found any clue in the .map file.

Thanks!
Paweł

Comment: Drogi Kolego Pawle - a dlaczego Cię to tak niepokoi. (I've asked Pawel what does he worry about). Does it make any difference what is in the hex file? I think that actually loaded content is important

Comment: @PeterJ, I'm just curious. I like to know why something happens. The problem doesn't mean worry here.

Comment: Did you look in the .map file already?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As I've said - no information in the .map file (the last section mentioned is 3 bytes at 0x08006E00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to look in the `.map` file to see what it's putting there. But it can be your code, or a library. You are using an absolute address, not a relative reference to the "end of image".

Instead, use a custom [linker file](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1362075656353.htm) to **explicitly** link that table to the end of the image.

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x0007000 {
    ; Program ROM Area
    ER_IROM1 0x08000000 (0x0007000-3) {
        *.o (RESET, +First)
        *(InRoot$$Sections)
        .ANY (+RO)
    }

    ; Program SRAM Area
    RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00001000 {
        .ANY (+RW +ZI)
    }

    ; Version area
    VERSION (0x08000000 + (0x0007000-3)) 0x3 {
        version.o
    }
}
```

*I have no idea about your target layout, adjust the numbers yourself.*
*Once on a sunny day I wrote a [little tool](https://github.com/Jeroen6/MapViewer) to read the map file. Maybe it works on your version of keil?*

**Update:**
You've shared the .sct file (linker file).

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000 {
    ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000 { 
        *.o (RESET, +First) *(InRoot$$Sections) 
        .ANY (+RO) 
    } 
    RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00001000 
    { 
        .ANY (+RW +ZI) 
    } 
}
```

Your ROM region LR_IROM1 spans from `0x08000000` to `0x08007FFF`.
**Therefore `0x08006E00` isn't the end of your image** and the linker is allowed to put anything (.ANY) after the statically linked object `AppVersion`.

If you don't want that, explicitly tell the linker to create a region only for your `version` object as in the example above.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've tried with the MapViewer, but it gives me the same impression as reading the very .map file. No information on anything except those 3 bytes at the end of the memory (.ARM.__AT_0x08006E00 of size 3 that's a section and AppVersionE at the same address and of the same size which is data).

Comment: @PawełJ could you share the .sct file?

Comment: Here you go:

LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000  {    ; load region size_region
  ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00008000  {  ; load address = execution address
   *.o (RESET, +First)
   *(InRoot$$Sections)
   .ANY (+RO)
  }
  RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 0x00001000  {  ; RW data
   .ANY (+RW +ZI)
  }
}